# Webform mails are uncomplete and go to spam

Tags: webform-civicrm, email

I use a lot of webforms which send mails when completed
I have just upgraded to 5.24.4, and since then :

- the mail goes to spam
- subject is empty
- tokens are empty : I get :

Submitted on

Submitted by user:

Submitted values are:

The results of this submission may be viewed at:

Any help is welcome

Comment: The Emails you're describing with Submitted on, by user and values are -> are generated by Drupal (not CiviCRM). Scan the drupal log for error messages.

Comment: Thank you Karin : actually, everything works on a test config that I just have reinstalled from scratch. I think that when I upgraded to 5.24.4, I reused old settings files which were not appropriate. And your answer helped me.

Comment: Getting a bit further, I change for a new question : "Tokens are not populated in the mail sent by webforms" (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35694/tokens-are-not-populated-in-the-mail-sent-by-webforms)